# Setting DataContext of a Window WPF/Caliburn/VB.NET

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, caliburn.micro

I have a project that needs a Window with at least 2 ViewModels, one for the basic logic and one for resizing the window dynamically. I can't figure out how to set the DataContext of the window to be the `WindowViewModel`, the window currently pulls all information from the `ShellViewModel`. Typically in C#, you could do this in the code-behind of the Window:

```
this.DataContext = new WindowViewModel(this)
```

But in VB, `Me.DataContext` doesn't even exist.

**Window View Model**

```
Imports Caliburn.Micro

Namespace MVVM
Public Class WindowViewModel
    Inherits ShellViewModel
    ''This class handles all form resizing and window properties

    Public Sub New(mWindow As Window)
        Window = mWindow
    End Sub

    Private _window As Window 'Window we are manipulating

    Public Property Window() As Window
        Get
            Return _window
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Window)
            _window = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
End Namespace
```

**ShellViewModel**

```
Namespace MVVM
Public Class ShellViewModel
    Inherits PropertyChangedBase

    Sub New()
        FormLoad()
    End Sub

    ///Logic code here

End Class
End Namespace
```

How can I link both ViewModels to the Window?

Comment: @mm8 Then how can I separate my WindowResizing code from my regular logic? isn't MVVM all about separation of concerns?

Comment: How do I reference the window if I can't use `Me` in my ShellView? or anywhere else for that matter

Comment: Is `ShellView` a window or a `UserControl`?

Comment: `ShellView` is a Window

Comment: So put your view-related code directly in the code-behind? Caliburn.Micro, by convention, sets the `DataContext` of the `ShellView` to an instance of a `ShellViewModel`.